# How to get HTML generated at runtime and control imagery based on host header and lookup table in .ASP.Net

Tags: c#, html, .net, asp.net-mvc, content-management-system

There are 3 concepts each type of user loggin in.  The imagery is controlled by a lookup table based on the host header.  By this, I mean that there are several domain names that point to the same IP/web instance, and that instance serves up the content based on reading the host header.

What we are doing now by having all the HTML (not the code) stored in a table that is referenced by the host header lookup.

CAn somebody guide me on this requirement please? Thanks

Answer (score 2):

There are probably better ways to deal with multi-tenancy but let's assume you can't change any of that.  What you want is probably this

```
string domain = HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_HOST"];
```

You could map this `domain` onto a customer Id and store this in the user's cookie and look up based on this, mapping as necessary.  Or simply use domain directly for your table lookup.

Answer (score 1):

```
Request.Url.Host
```

This will give you the domain name such as: "www.example.com". I would recommend to store records including "view name" and "domain". Then, on your action, I would imagine something like this:

```
var record = db.HostRecords.Where(r => r.Domain == Request.Url.Host).FirstOrDefault();

var view = "Page.cshtml";

if (record != null){
    view = record.ViewName;
}

return View(view);
```